# Change default CMakeLists.txt created by KDevelop?

Tags: cmake, kdevelop

When I create a project, my `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(testttt)

add_executable(testttt main.cpp)

install(TARGETS testttt RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

But I want it to looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(testttt)

add_executable(testttt main.cpp)

install(TARGETS testttt RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

so that I have C++11 support by default. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDevelop project templates are implemented using Grantlee templating engine. [Here is](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/KDevelop/Creating_a_class_template) a manual how to add your own template.

Built-in templates are located in `/share/apps/kdevfiletemplates/templates`, you can use "Basic C++ project` as an example.